# Python 3.x Tkinter stuck with a bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas
import random



def button_y_pressed():
    x = random.choice(data)
    canvas.itemconfig(text1, text="French")
    canvas.itemconfig(text2, text=x["French"])
    window.after(3000, flip_card)
    canvas.itemconfig(text2, text=x["English"])


def flip_card():
    canvas.itemconfig(text1, text="English")
    canvas.itemconfig(canvas_image, image=back_image)


BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#B1DDC6"
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
window.geometry("900x780")
window.title("Flash Cards")

my_image_x = PhotoImage(file="images/wrong.png")
button_x = Button(image=my_image_x, highlightthickness=0)
button_x.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

my_image_y = PhotoImage(file="images/right.png")
button_y = Button(image=my_image_y, highlightthickness=0, command=button_y_pressed)
button_y.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

front_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_front.png")
canvas = Canvas(window, width=800, height=526, highlightthickness=0, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
canvas_image = canvas.create_image(400, 263, image=front_image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=50, pady=50)
back_image = PhotoImage(file="images/card_back.png")
text1 = canvas.create_text(400, 150, text="text1", font=("Arial", 40, "italic"))
text2 = canvas.create_text(400, 263, text="text2", font=("Arial", 60, "bold"))

data = pandas.read_csv("data/french_words.csv")
data = data.to_dict(orient="records")


button_y_pressed()


window.mainloop()
```

I want the program to show the french versiın of the word first after 3 sec it will flipp and show the english version bu instead in this code program shows the english version does not show the french version at all

Comment: `window.after(3000, flip_card)` does not work like `time.sleep(3)`, put `canvas.itemconfig(text2, text=x["English"])` inside `flip_card` for it to be visible after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `window.after(3000, flip)`, it will schedule to execute the function `flip` in >= 3000ms and execute the next line *immediately*, it will actually not wait 3000ms and execute `flip` and then continue to the next line (like `time.sleep(3)`). So everything you want to execute after the countdown must be put into the callback:

```py
def button_y_pressed():
    x = random.choice(data)
    canvas.itemconfig(text1, text="French")
    canvas.itemconfig(text2, text=x["French"])
    window.after(3000, flip_card)
    

def flip_card():
    canvas.itemconfig(text1, text="English")
    canvas.itemconfig(text2, text=x["English"])
    canvas.itemconfig(canvas_image, image=back_image)
```

Comment: `window.after(3000, lambda: flip_card(x))` and adding the parameter to `flip_card` makes this work. Or declaring `global x` . (But some people hate global variables)

Comment: @SanguineL But why?

Comment: @SanguineL: the simpler way to pass an argument using `after` is to do `window.after(3000, flip_card, x)`

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah, yes, that is simpler. Thank you.